# Is it possible to mix JUnit3 and JUnit4?

Tags: java, android, unit-testing, junit, junit4

I believe that you can help me solve problem connected with compabitility JUnit libraries.

The problem is that we develop mobile apps (android) and we're using test managment tool called SpiraTest. We want that unit test results will be exported to SpiraTest automatically so want use junit extension for Spiratest (made by Spira team). Problem is that it requires JUnit4 to integrate, what Android doesn't support.

What would you recommend to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say that if you are going to do unit testing of you own functionality it won't really matter if Android supports it or not, you just run the unit tests regardless of the Android SDK. However if you intent to use jUnit to work alongside Android, there is no way at the moment to do it that I'm aware of.

Comment: What do you think about Junit4Android library? Have you ever used it or has some experience?

Comment: I haven't used it, but it looks promising, give it a try, it might make your whole setup work. My only worry would be that because of using so many different pieces the testing environment would be too fragile. Let me know if it works

Comment: Hi, I got NoClassDefFoundError all the time (but I'm beginner), so I decided to change library/framework. Now I configured Robolectric and it looks good. I can easy execute JUnit4 and 3 tests for Android app :)